# Silverlight AutoCompleteBox on custom search

Tags: silverlight, autocompletebox

I have this object :

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person " + LastName;
    }
}
```

And this Collecion:

```
public ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

My AutoCompleteBox is :

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" FilterMode="Contains"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding EmployeeSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 MinimumPrefixLength="2"/>
```

When i search in the Persons collection i want search by FirstName? 
Which is the property in AutoCompleteBox for say search by FirstName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ValueMemberPath` :

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" FilterMode="Contains"
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding EmployeeSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                                 ValueMemberPath="FirstName"/>
```